# Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
          <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-y-2 md:gap-x-2 items-center">
            {post.categories.map((category) => (
              <div className="bg-[#f7ab0a] text-center text-black px-3 py-1 rounded-full text-sm font-semibold">
                <p>{category.title}</p> 
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEOu6.png)

I'm trying to add some category tags on my blog from my schema and I keep getting this error. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Try to add question marks ````post?.categories?.map((category)````

Answer (score 1):

It might happen when you're getting the data from some kind of server, and on the initial render of your component the data was not received yet, therefore you have nothing to map on at the moment.
The way you can handle it is by making sure that you have the data, before iterating on it.
Here's how you can do it:

```html
{post?.categories?.map((category) => (
   ...
 ))}
```

Alternatively you can test the array length, like this:

```html
{post.categories.length && post.categories.map((category) => (
   ...
 ))}
```

Comment: That totally fixed it! cheers.